# Strophe MUC invite decline handler not triggered

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I have a web-chat application with group-chat. Now I can invite other users to my room, I can listen to invitations and I can decline an invitation, but for some reason, when a user declines my invitation, it doesn't trigger my onDecline method. Here's the part where I add the handler:

```
connection.addHandler(onDecline, Strophe.NS.MUC_USER);

//(Strophe.NS.MUC_USER = http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user)
```

I get the following XML when the user declines:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">
   <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="qvxuceluy@conference.127.0.0.1" to="hampel.elod_reea.net@127.0.0.1">
      <x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user">
         <decline from="40756382284@127.0.0.1">
            <reason>Busy!</reason>
         </decline>
      </x>
   </message>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message handler might be intercepting it. Make sure your message handler has "groupchat" or "chat" for the type (onMessage, null, 'message', 'chat'). Or you can handle it through your message handler.

Comment: This message doesn't have a type, as you can see, so I don't think that that will help. This is not a chat message and I already have both chat and groupchat type handlers

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I was very clear. So, my onDecline method needs to be triggered when a user declines my invitation(when I get the XML from above).

Comment: Does your message handler have a type included? If not, it'll intercept the decline. Use logging and check to make sure it's not going to your message handler.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. The decline message triggered the message handler.